# friendly URL - two variables in the URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I need help me with some URL rewriting using `.htaccess`.

I would like to use this URL:

```
www.mydomain.com/page.php?var1=NY&var2=New York
```

And convert it to:

```
www.mydomain.com/page1/New York
```

That should be done without losing the first parameter of course.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (with the appropriate RewriteBase):

```
            RewriteRule ^page.php?var1=([^&]+)&var2=([^&])$ /page1/$2?var1=$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Post your entire mod_rewrite configuration.